# "No problem" or "no problems"?

Tags: phrases

I study English and I ran into a problem.
What version is correct:
"no problem" or "no problems"?

P.S. Is "ran into a problem" correct?
P.P.S. Is version correct word for this situation? May be "variant"?

Comment: You seem to have run into more than one problem, at least three.

Comment: As Kris points out, please do not ask several unrelated questions per question. Also, please provide context — as you can see from the answer, both versions are grammatical in and of themselves. Lastly, you might be interested in our proposed sister site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). You can support it by committing. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends.

If the following case

> Can you finish on time? Yes. No problem.

you use the singular form.

On the contrary, in a phrase like:

> I carefully examined your solution, and found no problems in it.

you can also use the plural form, indicating that you examined more than one possible problems in the suggested solution.